# How can we add third party select-picker/date-picker in react js?

Tags: reactjs

i would like to add third party date-picker/select-picker component in react with rails application. Is there any convenient method or any attractive plugins available ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always take a look at [MaterialUI](https://material-ui.com/) which is a popular UI library for React.

[MaterialUI Pickers](https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/)